# Forms Authentication Behavior

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cookies, webforms

net forms authentication. What I understand from reading post is that the forms authentication sets a token in a cookie that times out based on configuration settings. Then when the user refreshed their page if the cookie token has expired, the user gets redirected to the login page. Is that correct?

If so I have a problem with the cookie time out. Please indicate where I'm lacking some understanding.

I created a 2014 webforms project. I added a 'Secured' folder with 2 webforms and a web.config file. The web config for the folder is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I then changed my Application Web.config. The authentication section is as follows:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="FORM_AUTH" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" 
        loginUrl ="~/Account/Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="1"/>
</authentication>
```

I then added the page menu links.

On starting the app I get taken to the login screen. But when I leave the page sitting for 5 min with no input and then click refresh or move to the other secured webform, I do not get sent to the login screen, but rather the pages display with no problem.

Thanks for your suggestions and help!

Comment: Could the secured pages be cached?

Comment: They may be, but this is a new project just to help me figured out how to implement forms authentication. So they would not have been just before posting here.

Comment: Also I just started application insights. It shows 1 user and one session still. So if I understand what insights is saying. Forms Authentication Timeout has still not happened.

Comment: session timeout and forms authentication ticket timeout are completely independent of each other.

Comment: Sorry , I did not mean to indicate that I am doing anything with sessions. I am only reporting what insight is reporting. I'm only trying to get forms auth to time out. The one user was what I was looking at. I suppose that could be an unauthenticated user. Still the pages are not acting the way I have read they should act.

Comment: what happens if you do a POST on one of the secured pages (e.g. by clicking on an ASP.NET button)?  POST should not be cached, so if this still fails to redirect, it probably eliminates caching as a potential source of your problem.

Comment: Joe, thanks for the suggestion. I put a button on one of the secured pages, along with a label. On button_click I set the label to 'clicked'. That worked fine even after 3 minutes of inactivity. So again it seems the forms authentication is not timing out.

Comment: Could you please check the expire time of the authentication cookie (FORM_AUTH) in your browser? I'm thinking that the authentication cookie is sliding. If after one minute, the auth cookie is still there and the time always increases by one minute then something might cause the auth cookie to slide. If that is the case, you can try for testing purposes to set the slidingExpiration to false.

Comment: Michael M, thank you for the suggestion. The localhost cookie expired at 10:23am. It is now 10:34 am and the secured pages are still functioning(the button click is still change lbl text without requiring login)

Comment: how do we keep up a conversation here? we are not suppose to keep comments running. Anyway now I'm thoroughly confused. I deleted the localhost cookie, the secured pages still function.

Comment: To debug this I would set a break point in the global.asax Application_AuthenticateRequest event handler.  Check if the user is anonymous or authenticated.  Decrypt and inspect the forms authentication ticket.